# striped background in Victory chart

Tags: css, victory-charts

I am trying to create a bar chart with Victory and I need to customise the background. I know there is a `Background` component and by adding these lines to a `VictoryChart` you can change the background color:

```
  <VictoryChart
    padding={{left:100, top:50, bottom: 50, right: 10}}
    domainPadding={{x: 20}}
    domain={{ y: [0, 4] }}
    theme={VictoryTheme.material}
    tickFormat={(tick) => `${tick}`}
    style={{
       background: { 
         fill: "black"
       }
    }}
    backgroundComponent={ <Background /> }
  />
```

I need however to have a striped background, with 4 different colours, one for each y value - i.e. from 0 to `basso` is green, from `basso` to `medio` is orange and so on...

Is this something that can be achieved with Victory? Any advice more than welcome

[image]

Comment: Can you post a working example of what you got. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I tried to pass svg linearGradient as background fill color. I attached a link to working demo below.

```
<svg>
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="radial_gradient" gradientTransform="rotate(90)">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#190b28" />
        <stop offset="25%" stop-color="#190b28" />
        <stop offset="25%" stop-color="#434238" />
        <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#434238" />
        <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#334110" />
        <stop offset="75%" stop-color="#334110" />
        <stop offset="75%" stop-color="#524800" />
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#524800" />
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tatkpg?file=src/App.js

Comment: I just realised that your solution is actually producing a lot of white space on the page... did you realise that?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what your code looks like, I'll try this.
replace the current `black` bg with a linear gradient.

This solution assumes that each Y axis element is evenly spaced and only 4 of the, though if you need more than 4 just add them.

```
background: rgb(30,115,14);
background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(30,115,14,1) 0%, rgba(30,115,14,1) 25%, rgba(212,92,15,1) 25%, rgba(212,92,15,1) 50%, rgba(6,82,169,1) 50%, rgba(6,82,169,1) 75%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 75%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 100%);
```

Comment: I have edited my code to show the context where this should be inserted